# OnDateSetListener() not getting called

Tags: android, android-datepicker

When I change date, `OnDateSetListener()` is not being called. Even `setMinDate(day);` line is not working. I think for some reason `DatePickerDialog` has not registered `OnDateSetListener()`. But not able figure it out. I have declared both dialog and listener as global.

```
private DatePickerDialog datePicker;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener;
```

**Code :**

```
// Create dialogs for datePicker
private void createDatePicker() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, year, month, day);
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(day);

    dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Date changed.");
        }
    };

}

private void setEditTextListeres() {
        myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "EditText gained focus.");
                    datePicker.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any idea why listener is not being called? And why setMinDate() is not working?

Comment: Try putting `datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, year, month, day);` after `dateListener` is defined.

Comment: @Rapunzel I was trying the same. It calls the listener but twice. And setMinDate() is still not working.

Comment: where u called createDatePicker().

Comment: @Sam in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: `setMinDate()` method is working now. I was passing wrong value in method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the `DatePickerDialog` after you declared the listener, like Rapunzel said.

The listener will not work, because `dateListener` is null when you create `DatePickerDialog` instance. The `DatPickerDialog` object will not detect changes made to your listener.

**EDIT**:

Because dateListener is null at the time of calling DatePickerDialog(). If you look at the [source](http://goo.gl/P04hz) of the DatePickerDialog, you'll see the private final OnDateSetListener mCallback. That means it references to null. That reference becomes immutable, since it is final. dateListener = new DatePickerDailog.OnDateSetListener will create the instance somewhere else in the memory (because of the new keyword), causing the reference to change. The reference in DatePickerDialog.mCallback will not change, since it is immutable.

Comment: I already tried that and listener method in getting called. But I wonder why `DatePickerDialog` will not see changes to listener, because it has a reference of it. And having reference means having the latest copy.

Comment: Because dateListener is `null` at the time of calling `DatePickerDialog()`. If you look at the [http://goo.gl/P04hz](source) of the `DatePickerDialog`, you'll see the `private final OnDateSetListener mCallback`. That means it references to `null`. That reference becomes immutable, since it is final. `dateListener = new DatePickerDailog.OnDateSetListener` will create the instance somewhere else in the memory (because of the `new` keyword), causing the reference to change. The reference in `DatePickerDialog.mCallback` will not change, since it is immutable.

Comment: Could you run your app in debug mode and look up what `DatePickerDialog.mCallback` contains after calling `dateListener = new DatePickerDailog.OnDateSetListener`. I'm curious what you'll find.