# OnDateSetListener is not called

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360215/ondatesetlistener-not-getting-called) but nothing helped me. The listener is still not called.
Here is my code:

```
private void callDatePicker() {
        // получаем текущую дату
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        dl = new OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String editTextDateParam = dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year;
                date_text.setText(editTextDateParam);
                Log.d("BIMI", editTextDateParam);
            }
        };

        // инициализируем диалог выбора даты текущими значениями
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dl, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                            String editTextDateParam = mDay + "." + (mMonth + 1) + "." + mYear;
                            Log.d("GROM", editTextDateParam);
                            date_text.setText(editTextDateParam);
                        }
                    }
                });

        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

callDatePicker is called in the AlertDialog when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set both `BUTTON_POSITIVE` click listener and `OnDateSetListener` then only the positive button click will be called. If you want to call `OnDateSetListener` then don't set the button. If you need to change properties of a button like color,text then do it on `setOnShowListener`. So your final code will look something like this.

```
private void callDatePicker() {
        // получаем текущую дату
        int mYear,mMonth,mDay;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dl = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String editTextDateParam = dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year;
//                date_text.setText(editTextDateParam);
                Log.d("BIMI", editTextDateParam);
            }
        };

        // инициализируем диалог выбора даты текущими значениями
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dl, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        datePickerDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button pButton = datePickerDialog.getButton (DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                pButton.setText ("Set date");
            }
        });

        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```